# Starting new activity does not pause current

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onpause

in my Code I am calling a new activity but the old one gets not paused

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        float[] userCordinates = new float[2];

        userCordinates[0] = x;
        userCordinates[1] = y;
        userSequence.add(userCordinates);
        for (int r = 0; r < copySeq.size(); r++) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) (findViewById((Integer) copySeq.get(r)));
            int[] loc = new int[2];
            iv.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
            float xRangeMax = iv.getRight();
            float xRangeMin = iv.getLeft();
            float yRangeMax = iv.getBottom();
            float yRangeMin = iv.getTop();

            Integer point = (Integer)copySeq.get(r);

            if (x <= xRangeMax && x >= xRangeMin
                && y <= yRangeMax && y >= yRangeMin) { 
                if(copyColor.get(r).equals("green")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChildLevel.class);
    startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When the new `Activity` is started this code snip in the current `Activity` is executed but it should be executed when I am coming back. E.g. this `Activity` should be paused at exactly in this point.

```
    if (userSequence.size() >= finalSequence.size()) {
        childLevel=false;
        save();
        check(userSequence);
        touchView.setEnabled(false);
    }
}    
return false;
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: the second code snippet is inside ChildLevel activity?

Comment: @ Matias Elorriaga no the second snippet belongs to the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the `ChildLevel` Activity, the current one (lets call it `MainActivity`) is paused (`onPause()` method is called).

If you want the second code snippet to be executed when you go back to `MainActivity`, put that code inside `onResume()` method in `MainActivity`

EDIT: so, you only need to execute that piece of code when you go back to `MainActivity` from `ChildLevel`. You need to use `startActivityForResult()`:

In `MainActivity`, instead of `startActivity()`, use `startActivityForResult()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChildLevel.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 123);
```

Then, in ChildLevel, when you want to go back:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Finally, in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            // the code you want to execute
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but when I am putting it in onResume the ocde gets also executed when the activity resumes from other resons for example after pressing the home button, in this case the snippet should not be executed

Comment: yes, you said "but it should be executed when I am coming back".. what exactly do you want? please be clearer

Comment: the snippet should be executed when I am coming back from the new activity I called before

Comment: ok, so you need to startActivityForResult.. let me update my answer